# How to update environment variable in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, aws-codeartifact

We are using AWS CodeArtifact to store our maven dependencies. Also, the company I work for uses temporary access keys to access aws. To make a long story short, every hour you have to run a script that updates your ~/.aws/credentials with the new keys. You also need to get a new CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN to access CodeArtifact.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/tokens-authentication.html#env-var

How can you make IntelliJ pickup the new CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN? Since you have to get a new one every hour you can't just set it in the settings. Well, of course you can, but you'll have to update it every hour...

Is it possible to do automagically?

Comment: Normally processes inherit parent's environment variables and do not update it on the fly unless the specific code is written to handle such cases. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have such code. When you say IntelliJ IDEA, what exact process should have access to the new environment? IDE Java process, JVM process with the code you run? JVM process running Maven? The process running Terminal?